# Calculating Pseudo-elements as Part of Element's Width

Tags: html, css

Right now I have a button with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements that is set to a 90% of the width of its parent div. However, I can't seem to get the pseudo-elements to be calculated in this 90%. Essentially, what I want is the `border-box` CSS rule but with pseudo-elements. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<button type"submit">Send</button>
```

CSS

```
.contact button {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.contact button::after,
.contact button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
}
.contact button::after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
}
.contact button::before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, -3px);
  transform: translate(-3px, -3px);
}
```

Here's a link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/XpBMwM?editors=1100

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what the contact button should look like before and after hover? I don't understand..

Comment: If you want border-box, why would you not use border-box?

Comment: @ovokuro Before hover, the button's sides should line up perfectly with the textarea's sides. On hover, the button's width (including pseudo-elements) should be slightly less than the textarea's.

Comment: @Sandro I am already applying that rule to everything on the page. I mentioned border-box as more of an example than a literal idea.

Comment: But you've applied transform: translate to the pseudoelements - you're specifically telling the `:before` to be -3px away from the edge.

Comment: Also, I don't see anywhere that the button's width is set at 90%

Comment: @ovokuro Sorry, I meant 70%. It's at line #215.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix I found was this:

```
left: 3px;
right: 3px;
```

For both pseudo-elements.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks for reading into what I meant ;)